# Beginner Question in PostgreSQL concerning LIKE command

Tags: postgresql, sql-like

I just started learning SQL today and was wondering if I can create a Data Output that includes Titles that starts with S and T together using the Like command?

Here is my query:

```
select title, length, replacement_cost 
from film 
where title like 'S%' and 'T%'
and replacement_cost between 15.99 and 20.99 
order by length desc limit 20
```

I tried using

```
-like 'S%' and 'T%'
-like ('S%','T%')
-like ('S% and 'T%')
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: How can a title start with both S and T? Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: You are probably looking for an OR: `where (title like 'S%' OR title like 'T%') and ...`

Comment: I just needed an OR and it worked! thank you so much!